# Accidentally Wiped out Hard Disk With Windows 8 while installing ubuntu 13.04, Is there any way to recover?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8, data-recovery

I brought my Dell Inspiron 15R (5521) laptop yesterday only, I tried to installing ubuntu 13.04 as I go along with installation (I selected first option for selecting disk) I think wiped out entire Hard disk there.

When I reboot my machine it says-

[checking media] - failed

[checking media] - failed

and Then
"No bootable device found, Please enter any key to reboot"

I wanted to create dual boot machine with Windows 8 and ubuntu. I little confused what went wrong.

Is there any way I can get Back my original Windows 8? 
So that I will able to install ubuntu again. 
( I didn't created any backup disk neither I have Windows 8 DVD).

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Ubuntu bootable disc or USB device, use it to boot up your machine. Then select `Try Ubuntu` and check if your HDD has the Windows files or not and let me know.

Comment: NO, I ran ubuntu in 'Try Unbuntu' mode and see only one partition and on HDD and that too formatted with Ext4 partition.

Comment: Then the only way to recover your laptop is to use the Dell Recovery partition as stated by @Pitto.

Answer (score 1):

use GParted on ubunte like got to change the formate but do not formate it then got to recover disk that work for me but you will need 2 hard drive the one you want the stuff off and one to copy the stuff on cus i did the with my 3tb can got all my stuff back that should work but do not format it just keep it up in the back screen the just recover it

Answer (score 1):

You can just hope that you've messed up *only* your boot partition.

I see two solutions here:

a) @Hrishi's idea is right so try that and if you are so lucky that your files are still sitting there further information are needed to understand how we can restore Windows boot loader or Grub to get your pc up and running again.

b) If you want it fast and easy (this sounds good to me because you say that the pc is brand new and I can suppose that you have no important data on it) simply use your Dell Inspiron recovery (looks like you need to press control+f11 at boot, read here: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7319-dell-inspiron-restore-to-factory-default-settings) and then start again with your perfectly working windows, ready to try ubuntu install again

For sure this is painful but it took me a nasty amount of formats to learn how to handle properly a dual boot. It was worth it, if you ask me :)